# android version 10 creating issue with manage external storage whereas the code is running fine with android 11

Tags: flutter

I am trying to download file. So in android 11 i need manage external storage permission. These permission i have given and they are working fine with android 11. downloading is happening and files are being stored. But when i work with android 10 then there is an error
no permissions found in manifest for 22 which i searched over internet and found that this is the error for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>



void getPermission() async {
var status = await Permission.storage.request();
var status3 = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
if (status.isGranted && status3.isGranted) {
  // print('granted');
  //var status2 = await Permission.accessMediaLocation.request();
  //if (status2.isGranted) {
  setState(() {
    _allowWriteFile = true;
  });
} else {
  // print("denied");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm having same issue I solve by doing this.For android 10 you have to give permission in mainActivity,

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
            setupPermissions()
        }
    }

    private fun setupPermissions() {


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this@MainActivity,
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity,
                    arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity,
                    arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69759723/restricted-access-to-external-storage-android-10 this link is also helpful

Answer (score -1):

try adding the following in the android manifest file, inside application tag.

```
 <application
   android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ...  </application>
```